# How to hide/show NSCell object from NSMatrix

Tags: objective-c, macos, appkit

I would like to hide the NSCell object from NSMatrix. Based on some other action I would like to display NSCell again (in same row and same column), thru programatically. 
It seems easy to disable/enable, but not hide/show. Any help much appreciated

Comment: What's the issue when you try doing it?

Comment: We have legacy code dynamically draws NSCell items inside the NSMatrix. In some scenario. some of the NSCell items are disabled, in some other scenario those are enabled. Now the requirement is, we want hide/show instead of disable/enable

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding/showing cells, you can only remove or add cells. So you can display different groups of cells based on different scenarios to work around.

Refer to [Managing the Matrix’s Cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Matrix/Tasks/ManagingMatrixCells.html) from "Matrix Programming Guide".

Comment: Thanks Winter. Finally removing and adding